# Adding Columns Dynamically to a MySQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hello & good afternoon,

I am developing an online product returns form which depending on the number of products the customer wants to return asks for the serial number of each one then i want to store each serial number in a MYSql database.

I just want to make sure i am creating the relevant number of columns the most efficient way & my code is as follows: -

```
if (isset($_POST['system_checkbox'])) 
{
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $qty; $i++)
  {
    mysqli_query($db, "ALTER TABLE credit_table ADD Serial_Number_$i VARCHAR(255)");
  } 
}
```

As you can see i am just using a basic for loop so each column is creating columns Serial_Number_1, Serial_Number_2, etc with $qty being the number of products being returned.

I also want to write the value of each serial number field from the form into the relevant columns which is where I become stuck.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Lee.

Comment: I dont think its a good idea to add columns freely like that

Comment: Dont do it that way use another table to hold this data

Comment: Okay, so i have two tables.  Table one contains the customer info & tabe 2 contains details of the product being returned including the serial number(s).  How would you propose I approach this differently?

Comment: Education, education, education. Read some tutorials on database design. Take a course. Employ someone who has a clue. Basically you dont have the knowledge or experience to do the job you are attempting. GET HELP. But this is not the place t get it.

Answer (score 1):

Please read up on 3NF - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form = You should not be altering databases except in unusual circumstances and then it is a one off event